# Terraform RDS module : support for oracle

Tags: rds, terraform

Does RDS module from terraform supports the Oracle RDS. The module I tried using is: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws/1.0.8
When I use it for Oracle, we always need to provide the license_model parameter but this module does not seem to have this parameter and hence, I always get an error as below :

1 error(s) occurred:
module root: module db: license_model is not a valid parameter

Please correct me if I am missing something.

Thanks
Neeraj

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved and license_model has been added to rds module. Here is the link :

[RDS Oracle support](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-rds/issues/15)